# Displaying last 4-digit credit card

Tags: php, wordpress

I am just developing an ecommerce platform using Wordpress and MIGS plagin 
I am having little trouble in displaying last 4-digit number of customer. I'm trying to edit thankyou.php file that contains customer information but no variable regarding the card is being used.

These are customer details of thankyou.php file

```
    <ul class="order_details order_summary">
        <li class="order">
            <?php esc_html_e('Order:', 'rossi'); ?>
            <strong><?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?></strong>
        </li>
        <li class="date">
            <?php esc_html_e('Date:', 'rossi'); ?>
            <strong><?php echo date_i18n(get_option('date_format'), strtotime($order->order_date)); ?></strong>
        </li>
        <li class="total">
            <?php esc_html_e('Total:', 'rossi'); ?>
            <strong><?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total(); ?></strong>
        </li>
        <?php if ($order->payment_method_title) : ?>
        <li class="method">
            <?php esc_html_e('Payment method:', 'rossi'); ?>
            <strong><?php echo $order->payment_method_title; ?></strong>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I thought it was as easy as it sounds but I don't know where to start

Any help is very appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Your code does not show any instance where the credit card digits are being shown. And also your question is not that clear.

Comment: When you dont know where to start, ___You should start by reading the manual___ [See String Functions in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

Comment: Don't laugh at me please, because I don't know how to get the credit card digits instance. But I think it is somewhere in MIGS plagin

Answer (score 7):

Try this code:

You can use `str_pad()` function show last 4 digit of credit card.

```
<?php
    $number =  "1122334455667788";
    $masked =  str_pad(substr($number, -4), strlen($number), '*', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    print $masked; //************7788
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$output[mcard_Number] = "5105105105105100";

$mcardNum = str_replace(range(0,9), "*", substr($output[mcard_Number], 0, -4)).substr($output[mcard_Number], -4);

echo $mcardNum;
```

Comment: Hi Diksha, welcome to SO! Please add some info in your answers and not only code, to better help the community. Also remember to format your code using Ctrl+K

Comment: Hi Jacopo, thank you for letting me know how to format the code but actually its not working.
But next time I will remember to format my code.